# How to get the recent first post and second ... to put them in a slid show in blogger templet

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

UPDATE

I just want a function to extract the last 3 posts by date, while preparing the Blogger template, and it must be a separate function to extract each separate post (first - second - third) and then include it in the slide show attached in the code below

I just want a function to extract the last 3 posts from Blogger blog and that is to be used in below code

https://github.com/ahmedmehanna700/post-code

I have a  bootstrap slider that shows the recent posts I want to get 3 posts title and image and put them in img scr  and p I want to bring each item separately in order to be able to place it inside the code

Comment: "*...place it inside the ؤخيث*" -> What means "**ؤخيث**"?

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear.
This code creates a list of images and titles:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-item"),
    list = [];

for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
  let data = {};
  data.img = items[i].querySelector("img");
  data.title = items[i].querySelector(".carousel-caption > h5");
  list[list.length] = data;
}

console.log("Title from second post: ", list[1].title.textContent);
console.log("Image url from third post: ", list[2].img.src);
console.log("list of all posts:");
console.log(list);
```

```html
<div class='flex-grow widget-inner'>
 
                  
                       <div class='carousel slide' data-bs-ride='carousel' id='carouselExampleCaptions'>
  <div class='carousel-indicators'>
    <button aria-current='true' aria-label='Slide 1' class='active' data-bs-slide-to='0' data-bs-target='#carouselExampleCaptions' type='button'/>
    <button aria-label='Slide 2' data-bs-slide-to='1' data-bs-target='#carouselExampleCaptions' type='button'/>
    <button aria-label='Slide 3' data-bs-slide-to='2' data-bs-target='#carouselExampleCaptions' type='button'/>
  </div>
  <div class='carousel-inner'>
    <div class='carousel-item active'>
      <img alt='...' class='d-block w-100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qq6KbFXzexw/YHoA4BaCfBI/AAAAAAAAF-8/o93DIHz4xa4zMMyYfmX_hDEDrUUardirwCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/%25D9%2585%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B1%25D8%25A7%25D8%25A9%2B%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25A3%25D9%2587%25D9%2584%25D9%2589%2B%25D9%2588%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B2%25D9%2585%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2583%2B18-4-2021.webp'/>
      <div class='carousel-caption d-none d-md-block'>
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel-item'>
      <img alt='...' class='d-block w-100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vYM4UIdLty4/YHnxtDr8IcI/AAAAAAAAF-0/1JR8EZpgtIEyRlW7sffau6ost0dVJWlaQCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/%25D8%25A8%25D8%25AB%2B%25D9%2585%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D8%25B4%25D8%25B1%2B%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D8%25B4%25D9%2584%25D9%2588%25D9%2586%25D8%25A9%2B%25D9%2588%25D8%25A7%25D8%25AA%25D9%2584%25D8%25AA%25D9%258A%25D9%2583%2B%25D8%25A8%25D9%2584%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D9%2588%2B%2B%25D8%25A8%25D8%25AF%25D9%2588%25D9%2586%2B%25D8%25AA%25D9%2582%25D8%25B7%25D9%258A%25D8%25B9%2B%2B%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25A7%25D9%2586.webp'/>
      <div class='carousel-caption d-none d-md-block'>
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='carousel-item'>
      <img alt='...' class='d-block w-100' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RsLYxQ6LElo/YGFsiqK1zNI/AAAAAAAAF8s/PzyjKOyecNsDxVdxQ2GJ15fnJCESdXIigCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25AA%25D8%25B3%25D8%25AC%25D9%258A%25D9%2584%2B%25D9%2581%25D9%2589%2B%25D9%2584%25D9%2582%25D8%25A7%25D8%25AD%2B%25D9%2583%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%25D9%2588%25D9%2586%25D8%25A7%2B%25D9%2583%25D9%2588%25D8%25B1%25D9%2586%25D8%25A71.webp'/>
      <div class='carousel-caption d-none d-md-block'>
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class='carousel-control-prev' data-bs-slide='prev' data-bs-target='#carouselExampleCaptions' type='button'>
    <span aria-hidden='true' class='carousel-control-prev-icon'/>
    <span class='visually-hidden'>Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class='carousel-control-next' data-bs-slide='next' data-bs-target='#carouselExampleCaptions' type='button'>
    <span aria-hidden='true' class='carousel-control-next-icon'/>
    <span class='visually-hidden'>Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I just want a function to extract the last 3 posts while preparing the Blogger template, and it must be a separate function to extract each separate post (first - second - third) and then include it in the slide show attached in the code above

Comment: I just want a function to extract the last 3 posts from Blogger blog and that is to be used in the previous code (slider)

Comment: I just want a function to extract the last 3 posts from Blogger blog and that is to be used in the previous code (slider)

Comment: extract from what? The code above extracts the data from the code you've provided, with it you can include whatever you need from that data into whatever else you need...

Comment: I want the opposite. Extract from my site (use the Blogger template) to put it in that code ... "Just forget the code at the top. I just want a function to extract the last 3 posts from my site according to the date, knowing that I use Blogger."

Comment: So, exactly how would anyone know what is your website? Just look at the code posted and adopt it to your website, same concept I suppose.

Comment: this is the code https://github.com/ahmedmehanna700/post-code